# How to create map in R from spatial polygon given as list data type

Tags: r, spatial, r-sp, r-maptools

I have a list (imported from Stata dta file) containing entries defining spacial polygons for a map, to give an idea:

```
> typeof(aux3)
[1] "list"
> mode(aux3)
[1] "list"
> head(aux3)
  _ID        _X       _Y
1   1        NA       NA
2   1 -22.23933 64.56315
3   1 -22.25667 64.56053
4   1 -22.25026 64.56653
5   1 -22.27167 64.57319
6   1 -22.30311 64.55409
> tail(head(aux3,20000))
      _ID       _X       _Y
19995   2 21.21593 60.24696
19996   2 21.21650 60.24337
19997   2 21.23972 60.24913
19998   2 21.22203 60.23304
19999   2 21.21618 60.23332
20000   2 21.22092 60.23930
> #etc.
```

I would like to convert this into a data structure with which I can work to create a map (without larger difficulty and without needing extensive expertise, never having done that before) in R. I inferred that the SpacialPolygons type of the sp package is the easiest choice. Further, from the definition, it seemed that the SpacialPolygons method (defined in this package, see the [package's documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/sp.pdf), page 79) is the correct method to convert from list to this data type.

Unfortunately, the method is not that straightforward to work with and I need some help. My (naive) attempt yields an error that I do not understand and that does not turn up any interesting results in a google search:

```
> library(maptools)
Loading required package: sp
Checking rgeos availability: FALSE
    Note: when rgeos is not available, polygon geometry     computations in maptools depend on gpclib,
    which has a restricted licence. It is disabled by default;
    to enable gpclib, type gpclibPermit()
> SP<-SpatialPolygons(aux3)
Error in SpatialPolygons(aux3) : 
  cannot get a slot ("area") from an object of type "integer"
```

Can the list above be converted to SpacialPolygon? If so, how? If not, what format should I choose instead? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to draw the map, you could use ggplot. I can't test this since I don't have your data, but should work.

```
library(ggplot2)
aux_df <- data.frame(aux3)
# as per comment: the list-to-dataframe conversion prepends the column names with X
ggplot(aux_df, aes(x=X_X, y=X_Y, group=X_ID) + 
  geom_polygon(color='black', fill=NA) +
  coord_map() +
  theme_classic()
```

The above assumes the list `aux3` has longitude and latitude in `_X` and `_Y` and polygons defined by `_ID`. It applies a mercator projection by default, but you can change this using different arguments to `coord_map()`.

Here's a working example using a map of ohio counties (arbitrary choice).

```
library(ggplot2)
ohio_poly <- map_data('county', region='ohio')
ggplot(ohio_poly, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) +
  geom_polygon(color='black', fill=NA) +
  coord_map() +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works well. ... With one minor change: "... aes(x=X_X, y=X_Y, groups=X_ID)..." since the list-to-dataframe conversion prepends the column names with X.

Comment: Aha. Edited to reflect that